# Hide Global Locale in a route in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, routes, locale

In a Symfony2 project we are looking to show the different webpages without the locale at the url when language is set at default (en), like the following example:

1. http://www.thesiteimcoding.com/user/account =>show the EN version
2. http://www.thesiteimcoding.com/es/user/account => forced ES locale

So, I'm trying to create a double redirect in the routing.yml file like this:

```
locale_routing2:
  resource: routing2.yml
  prefix:  /
  defaults:
    _locale: en


locale_routing:
  resource: routing2.yml
  prefix: /{_locale}/
  requirements:
    _locale: fr|es
```

And in the routing2.yml file I have:

```
analytics:
    resource: "@AnalyticsBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /analytics
```

Also I tryed modify my routing.yml to something like:

```
software:
resource: "@SoftwareBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation
prefix:   /{_locale}/software/
requirements:
    _locale: |es|ca|pt_pt|fr|de|it|ja|ko|zh-hans
```

software2:
    resource: "@SoftwareBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /software/
    defaults:
        _locale: en

But it's just only working for the last block of routing, if i check the order of them it get in latest of routing methods.

So, my question is how to make it works? 
What I have to add to read the 2 ways of redirect to the controllers?

Or, It's there any way of hide somepart of the URL to don't show to the user the _locale ???

Thanks for your time. Ray.

Comment: Pretty sure you are just going to have to define two routes each pointing to the same controller.  Or move the locale to be a query parameter.

Comment: Finally, the only solution that I Found is just add F18BUNDLE.